# How to find the full path of sudo to run a command

Tags: linux, centos

So, got myself into a stickly situation here. A bad /etc/environment file locked up my system, and I can only run full-path commands, such as

```
    /usr/bin/nano
```

What's the full path like that to engage sudo?

Edit: which and type are off the table for this system.

Comment: Doesn't the `which` command or `type` command help you. Like `which sudo` or `type -a sudo` ?

Comment: This sounds more like it calls for a flatten and reload.

Comment: @Naai Sekar: which or type isn't being recognized as a command

Comment: @Davidw Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: The machine needs to be rebuilt, in other words.

Comment: Ideally, but a rebuild isn't likely at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS7, sudo can be found in /bin (which is a symlink to /usr/bin, by the way).

For convenience, you might consider manually setting the PATH variable to a workable minimum until you have resolved the problems with /etc/environment:

PATH=/sbin:/bin:$PATH

Comment: PATH is the issue here, all symlinks are broken. I'll try this out and report back.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH.
That will give you access to the most important commands you need to resolve the problem.

Comment: Ah. Current issue is that I needed SUDO to access the /etc/environment